# Problem getting an object array from a Set<Locale> in Android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

Do you see anything wrong with this code? I get the following error when the function executes: `java.lang.NullPointerException`: Attempt to invoke interface method `java.lang.Object[] java.util.Set.toArray()` on a null object reference. I run it in Android 7.0.

```
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.content.Context;


public static String GetLanguages(Object objcon) {
    Context context = (Context) objcon;
    TextToSpeech tts;

    tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new OnInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

        };
    });

    Set<Locale> loc = tts.getAvailableLanguages();
    Object[] objloc = loc.toArray();
    return Arrays.toString(objloc);

};
```

Comment: This means that `tts.getAvailableLanguages()` returned `null`

Comment: I use the Google tts. It cannot return null. Is there a problem with initialization of the TTS?

Answer (score 5):

You are getting null, because `TextToSpeech` need time to initialize. That's why you have to provide implementation of `OnInitListener` during initialization.

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // Now you can use tts
            Set<Locale> loc = tts.getAvailableLanguages();
            Object[] objloc = loc.toArray();

        };
    });
```

That approach require to use TextToSpeech as class variable, so you would need some kind of callback, to get the results out of `GetLanguages` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
List<Locale> localeList = new ArrayList<Locale>();
for (Locale locale : locales) {
    int res = tts.isLanguageAvailable(locale);
    if (res == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
        localeList.add(locale);
    }
}

return Arrays.toString(localeList);
```